# Is it possible to prevent env variables from ever being printed to stdout in python?

Tags: python, security

In my python app, secrets like api keys and db passwords are stored in the env vars of the machine running the python app (basically, ECS).

I am looking for a way to ensure that a dev on the team could *never* see those secrets. However, currently a simple `password = os.environ.get("db_password")` and `print(password)` would foil my security plans. It just leaves the risk high that a dev at any stage prints a secret, and that's persisted somewhere in logs for all time.

I have seen interesting interactions before, like in Git runners where I tried using bash to print Git secrets, and they printed as `"*******"`. I am wondering if there is a way to recreate this in python?

*Best idea at solution: overwrite the `sys.stdout.write` method to ensure that stdout messages always replace certain strings with `"*******"`. This would be exploitable though, because a dev could write a script logging many password attempts until they discover the secret value. I'm also not sure how I could prevent a dev from editing the python code where such a method overwrite were written.*

Comment: There is no way to prevent developers from accessing secrets if they are writing the code that needs to consume those secrets. You could reduce the chance of accidents by removing credentials from `os.environ` after you have read them.

Comment: The leading practice would be to not store the passwords in environment variables and use some sort of privileged access management (PAM) or key management solution that rotates the credentials shortly after use, but if not an option, you're gonna have to get creative. Perhaps abstract how the keys are accessed from the dev so they don't necessarily realize it's an environment variable. Security through obscurity won't stop a motivated dev, but just an idea

Comment: Developers who shouldn't have access to production credentials shouldn't be working on production machines. Set up a development environment for them.

Comment: Basically, if they can write and run scripts that use the environment variables, there's no way to prevent them from printing them. All data is fungible.

Comment: This is not a programming question - that would be "how do I implement this specification?" You are still trying to figure out the specification. You could possibly have a security question that might be on topic at [security.se].